# curl command failed on centOS

Tags: php, curl, centos, whm, twitter-digits

I'm using **curl** to communicate with **api.digits.com** on my dedicated server on centOS 7.2.

Until today, all worked fine. Now i'm facing an issue, the connection fail.

**curl command**

```
[root@serveur etc]# curl -Lv api.digits.com
* About to connect() to api.digits.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.44.68.9...
* Connection timed out
* Failed connect to api.digits.com:80; Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to api.digits.com:80; Connection timed out
```

**ping command**

```
[root@serveur etc]# ping api.digits.com
PING api.digits.com (192.44.68.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from api.digits.com (192.44.68.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=98.7 ms
64 bytes from api.digits.com (192.44.68.9): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=98.7 ms
64 bytes from api.digits.com (192.44.68.9): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=98.7 ms
64 bytes from api.digits.com (192.44.68.9): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=98.8 ms
64 bytes from api.digits.com (192.44.68.9): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=98.7 ms
64 bytes from api.digits.com (192.44.68.9): icmp_seq=6 ttl=55 time=108 ms
64 bytes from api.digits.com (192.44.68.9): icmp_seq=7 ttl=55 time=127 ms
^C
--- api.digits.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 98.713/104.132/127.041/9.886 ms
```

I disabled the firewall, added rule on /etc/hosts (192.44.68.9 api.digits.com), the issue still occur.

Any idea on what can block the connection ?

Comment: `telnet api.digits.com 80` what does it show?

Comment: @Harikrishnan telnet command result as `Trying 192.44.68.9... telnet: connect to address 192.44.68.9: Connection timed out`

Comment: That means connectivity issue. Check firewall rules.

Comment: I've disabled the firewall, it can still affect the connection ?

Comment: There can be multiple firewalls.

Comment: @Harikrishnan thanks for your help, how do i proceed ? I can use WHM  interface OR ssh

Comment: Contact your hosting provider.